# Api call using python and token_auth

Tags: python, api, token, matomo

```
    """
    #Collects basic metrics from Matomo installation and returns a pandas dataframe
    """
 
    token = os.getenv("token")
 
    # Build url string
    base_url = 'https://matomo.___.com/index.php?module=API'
    site_num = '&amp;idSite=1'
    return_format = '&amp;format=json'
    period = '&amp;period=day'
    date_range = '&amp;date=last30'
    method = '&amp;method=VisitsSummary.get'
    token_string = "&amp;token_auth=" + token
    my_url = base_url + site_num + return_format + period + date_range + method + token_string
 
 
    # send request for report
    r = requests.get(my_url)
 
    # parse and tidy collected data
    data = pd.DataFrame(r.json()).T
    data = data.reset_index()
 
    data.columns = [
        "date",
        "uniq_visitors",
        "users",
        "visits",
        "actions",
        "visits_converted",
        "bounces",
        "sum_visit_length",
        "max_actions",
        "bounce_rate",
        "actions_per_visit",
        "avg_time_on_site",
    ]
 
    return data
```

I am trying to get data from the matomo API using an `auth_token` and parameters by using above code but i am not able to access it and my url is not taking token code any one has idea how i can solve this

Answer (score 2):

Given that you are using the request library, passing parameters and headers can be done using the following params in your get call:

```
r = requests.get(my_url, params=payload)
```

In the same way, an auth token is usually passed within headers:

```
r = requests.get(my_url, params=payload, headers=headers)
```

Using this format you can simply create a headers object which contains your token_auth and directly pass your parameters in a payload object:

```
headers = {'token_auth': token}
payload = {'module':'API', 'idSite':1, 'format':'json', 'period':'day', 'date':'last30', 'method':'VisitsSummary.get'}
```

Since you are now passing your parameters in you get request, there is no need to add them to the end of your url. Thus, your url should stay as `https://matomo.___.com/index.php`. These can then be used within your params and headers respectively. Please note that this assumes that the matomo API places the token_auth in its headers such as most APIs do. If this is not the case you could pass it directly within the params payload.

Here is a global overview:

```
token = os.getenv("token")

# Get url, headers and params
my_url = 'https://matomo.___.com/index.php'
payload = {'module':'API', 'idSite':1, 'format':'json', 'period':'day', 'date':'last30', 'method':'VisitsSummary.get'}
headers = {'token_auth': token}


# send request for report
r = requests.get(my_url, params=payload, headers=headers)
```

---

Note this answers your question specifically regarding the API call and not the processing after.